# Hard Sphere Scattering in the high energies limit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, scattering, scattering-cross-section

> We see that $\delta_1$ decreases by $90^\circ$ each time $l$ increases by one unit. Thus, for an adjacent pair of partial waves, $\sin^2\delta_1+\sin^2\delta_{l+1}=\sin^2\delta_1+\sin^2(\delta_1-\pi/2) = \sin^2\delta_1+\cos^2\delta_1=1$, and with so many $l$-values contributing to (7.6.50), it is legitimate to **replace $\sin^2\delta_1$ by its average value, $\frac{1}{2}$.** The number of terms in the $l$-sum is roughly $kR$, as it is the average of $2l+1$. Putting all the ingredients together, (7.6.50) becomes $$\sigma_{\text{tot}}=\frac{4\pi}{k^2}(kR)^2\frac{1}{2}=2\pi R^2.  \tag{7.6.53} $$
>
> [From pg. 409 Sakurai - Hard sphere scattering high energies limit (bold my own).]

Why can you replace the $\sin^2(\delta_l)$ by $\frac{1}{2}$? Is it just calculating the average over a period like if it were a signal?

Comment: Hello Juan, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! I edited your question, but in the future, please use MathJax to format math in your posts and type up text instead of taking a photo of it. Thanks, and best of luck with your question!

Comment: The key is the 'so many l-values' bit - with enough different values you converge on the average.

Comment: Jon, thats correct. Thats exactly what im trying to understand and what Sakurai says. How can you say that in math language? maybe i can understand you better. Thanks in advance.